# How to use "verb" with "who"?

Tags: relative-pronouns, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

> It was difficult for me to complete the project with Drek because he is **one of those persons who think he is always right.**

Is the sentence above right?

I think it's not correct since *one of those persons* is singular. So, we have to use singular verb *thinks*.

So, the sentence would be

> It was difficult for me to complete the project with Drek because he is **one of those persons who thinks he is always right.**

Am I right about my thinking? Or is it referring to only *group of persons*?

Consider other sentences like

**He was one of those who goes to work by bike.**

And

**He was one of those who go to work by bike.**

*Which sentence is correct grammatically?*

Could you please tell me which one *who* refers to in the sentences and grammar regarding this usage?

Comment: Your are right. The relative pronoun *who* refers to "one of those persons".

Comment: It's probably not your concern here but I think if it's a sentence that you want to use in your writing piece I suggest _... because he thinks he is always right_. Good writing is concise and to the point. Wordiness is not reader-friendly.

Comment: @Yuri Okay, thank you. But if I want to say one of the two sentences above, which is better and _correct grammatically_?

Comment: @Ganesh.R The second one. Relative pronouns always agree with what they're referring to. Here it agrees with _one_. _One_ of my dogs _is_ sick.

Comment: @yuri Your example is quite different to the original. Here "one" is the unequivocal referent. But you can easily say "One of my dogs, which were sick, died." as well as "One of my dogs, which was sick, ran away."

Comment: @DRF in the question poposed by OP it is said _who think **he is always right**_. The correct version if you want to relate who to persons is _he is one of the persons who think **they** are always right_. Based on this, I'd say sentence two is the correct one.

Comment: @Ganesh.R I just read DRF's answer. And I think it explains almost everything. Any problem?

Comment: @Yuri Leave this sentence. Consider **He was one of those who goes to work by bike** and **He was one of those who go to work by bike**.  Which is correct grammatically?

Comment: @Ganesh.R huh got it :). Both, but **no.1** can be true in a very specific context. Number two is generally correct and the reason is that you're making _him_ a member of a **specific** group sharing a feature (here going to work on a bike). One of those (who are _those_?! Those who go to work by bike). I can think of just one context that it can be right and it's when you refer to a group that don't share the specific feature you're talking about. Look at this e.g. _you see all these students in this school? Mat is one of those who want**s** to be a climber_. Not all Ss want to be a climber.

Comment: @Yuri So, in general the verb should be plural in this case. Anyway _thank you very much_.

Comment: @Ganesh ur wlc. that's my take. Actually that's a clever question and I'd like to find a good answer to it. (Searching now) :)

Comment: *People* would be more natural than *persons* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is not addressing OP's sentences although it deals with OP's concern over *one of those noun who*)

Does the verb following *one of those noun who* agree with *one* or *those noun*? Both are fine.

> Where it is the subject that is relativised, the expectation would be that the number of the verb would be determined by the antecedent, giving a plural verb in Type I, and a singular in Type II. In practice, however, singular verbs are often found as alternants of plurals in Type I:
>
> [22] i He's [one of those people who always want to have the last word]. (Type I)
>
> ii He's [one of those people who always wants to have the last word]. (Type I)
>
> iii He's [one of her colleagues who is always ready to criticise her]. (Type II)
>
> Examples **[i]** and [iii] follow the **ordinary rules**, but **[ii]** involves **a singular override**. It can presumably be attributed to the salience within the whole structure of one and to the influence of the Type II structure (it is in effect a blend between Types I and II). But it cannot be regarded as a semantically motivated override: semantically the relative clause modifies people. **This singular override is most common when the relative clause follows these or those + noun** (520).

Source: *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Rodney Huddleston & Geoffrey K. Pullum*

Comment: Nice. I figured I'd try and check CGEL when I got home but you beat me to it. Very interesting.

Comment: @DRF The question was clever. BTW your take about _he_ instead of _they_ was brilliant. I didn't notice that before. I read your comment when I got back from work and it made me look again and think.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two examples you give the second one is correct, but for me the reason is not "one of those persons" but rather the "he". Let me give examples:

> Working with him was hard because he is one of those people/persons who think they are always right

Sounds perfectly fine to me. The reason I believe (and I'm not a linguist so take it with a grain of salt) is that the "who" can bind either to "one" or to "people". I.e. you can either parse it as "he is one of those (people who think they are always right)" or as "he is (one of those people) who thinks he is always right."

Notice that unless there is some other clue to the parsing you decide by the pronoun and that's less then perfect since there are situations where "they" might be a singular pronoun. Consider

> The patient was one of those people who thinks they are always right.

Here we are using a singular they to convey the fact we don't know whether the patient is male or female.

Comment: So, **who** can refer to either _he_ or _group of persons_. There is no certain rule regarding this. Right?

Comment: pretty much. It depends on how you parse it. But you really want to ask someone who is better at sentence deconstruction.

Comment: Many such people are here but no one is interested in answering my question.

Comment: @Ganesh.R As a native speaker, I would usually assume that "who" modifies the most recent noun, in this case "persons."  If it were modifying the entire phrase "one of those persons," I would expect a pause in speech between "persons" and "who."  In writing, I would put a comma after "persons" to represent this pause.  It's not required, but it makes the meaning clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is correct.  The pronoun "who" refers to "one", as in "he is one ... who thinks".

It's generally a good technique to drop prepositional phrases when you're trying to find out what a pronoun is referring to.